# Logs and eMail headers from THE Future"?

Tags: email, ipad, network

iPad Console Logs & eMail headers from the Future

---

What does the  "-700" mean in an eMail header when next to Date/Time Stampt?

I've noticed some of my iPad Console Logs display as +7hours AHEAD of the time they were collected.

And recently, I checked an eMail Header and noticed the same strange time shift when forwarded.  (specifically to /from certain recipients).

What does this mean?

I have not found any location  on our planet which is 7+ hours ahead of PST Time?

Answer (score 3):

The -700 is relative to [UTC time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_time) and used to describe the time zone. UTC-700 is used in [many places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC-07:00), probably including where you live.

The messages are shown with their UTC timestamp and the timezone offset. Subtract 7 hours from the time and you'll have the time in your local time zone. This is what computers do behind the scenes.

---

Also, one word of advice: the iPad console logs are meant for people developing software. If you're not doing that, looking through the logs is generally pointless. If things are working, don't worry about things you see in the logs :-)